# Scrapy crawler not getting data after crawling

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Im new to scrapy, but when I run my code the Debug returns with no errors and when I look at the amount of data it has scraped that should not be case? Below is my code. Im trying to get the reviews from tripadvisor.

```
import HTMLParser
import unicodedata
import re
import time

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule



class scrapingtestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "scrapingtest"

    allowed_domains = ["tripadvisor.com"]
    base_uri = "http://www.tripadvisor.com"
    start_urls = [
        base_uri + "/RestaurantSearch?geo=60763&q=New+York+City%2C+New+York&cat=&pid="
    ]




htmlparser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()

def is_ascii(s):
    return all(ord(c) < 128 for c in s)

def clean_parsed_string(string):
    if len(string) > 0:
        ascii_string = string
        if is_ascii(ascii_string) == False:
            ascii_string = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', ascii_string).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        return str(ascii_string)
    else:
        return None

def get_parsed_string(selector, xpath):
    return_string = ''
    extracted_list = selector.xpath(xpath).extract()
    if len(extracted_list) > 0:
        raw_string = extracted_list[0].strip()
        if raw_string is not None:
            return_string = htmlparser.unescape(raw_string)
    return return_string

def get_parsed_string_multiple(selector, xpath):
    return_string = ''
    return selector.xpath(xpath).extract()


def parse(self, response):
    tripadvisor_items = []

    sel = Selector(response)
    snode_restaurants = sel.xpath('//div[@id="EATERY_SEARCH_RESULTS"]/div[starts-with(@class, "listing")]')

    # Build item index.
    for snode_restaurant in snode_restaurants:
        # Cleaning string and taking only the first part before whitespace.
        snode_restaurant_item_avg_stars = clean_parsed_string(get_parsed_string(snode_restaurant, 'div[@class="wrap"]/div[@class="entry wrap"]/div[@class="description"]/div[@class="wrap"]/div[@class="rs rating"]/span[starts-with(@class, "rate")]/img[@class="sprite-ratings"]/@alt'))
        tripadvisor_item['avg_stars'] = re.match(r'(\S+)', snode_restaurant_item_avg_stars).group()

        # Popolate reviews and address for current item.
        yield Request(url=tripadvisor_item['url'], meta={'tripadvisor_item': tripadvisor_item}, callback=self.parse_search_page)





def parse_fetch_review(self, response):
        tripadvisor_item = response.meta['tripadvisor_item']
        sel = Selector(response)

        counter_page_review = response.meta['counter_page_review']

            # TripAdvisor reviews for item.
        snode_reviews = sel.xpath('//div[@id="REVIEWS"]/div/div[contains(@class, "review")]/div[@class="col2of2"]/div[@class="innerBubble"]')

        # Reviews for item.
        for snode_review in snode_reviews:
            tripadvisor_review_item = ScrapingtestreviewItem()

            tripadvisor_review_item['title'] = clean_parsed_string(get_parsed_string(snode_review, 'div[@class="quote"]/text()'))

            # Review item description is a list of strings.
            # Strings in list are generated parsing user intentional newline. DOM: <br>
            tripadvisor_review_item['description'] = get_parsed_string_multiple(snode_review, 'div[@class="entry"]/p/text()')
            # Cleaning string and taking only the first part before whitespace.
            snode_review_item_stars = clean_parsed_string(get_parsed_string(snode_review, 'div[@class="rating reviewItemInline"]/span[starts-with(@class, "rate")]/img/@alt'))
            tripadvisor_review_item['stars'] = re.match(r'(\S+)', snode_review_item_stars).group()

            snode_review_item_date = clean_parsed_string(get_parsed_string(snode_review, 'div[@class="rating reviewItemInline"]/span[@class="ratingDate"]/text()'))
            snode_review_item_date = re.sub(r'Reviewed ', '', snode_review_item_date, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
            snode_review_item_date = time.strptime(snode_review_item_date, '%B %d, %Y') if snode_review_item_date else None
            tripadvisor_review_item['date'] = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', snode_review_item_date) if snode_review_item_date else None

            tripadvisor_item['reviews'].append(tripadvisor_review_item)
```

Here's the DEBUG log

```
C:\Users\smash_000\Desktop\scrapingtest\scrapingtest>scrapy crawl scrapingtest -
o items.json
C:\Users\smash_000\Desktop\scrapingtest\scrapingtest\spiders\scrapingtest_spider
.py:6: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.spider` is deprecated, use `scra
py.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
C:\Users\smash_000\Desktop\scrapingtest\scrapingtest\spiders\scrapingtest_spider
.py:9: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.spiders` is deprecated,
use `scrapy.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
2015-07-14 11:07:04 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.1 started (bot: scrapingtest)

2015-07-14 11:07:04 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11

2015-07-14 11:07:04 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'sc

rapingtest.spiders', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapingtest.spi
ders'], 'FEED_URI': 'items.json', 'BOT_NAME': 'scrapingtest'}
2015-07-14 11:07:04 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter
, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-07-14 11:07:05 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddl
eware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultH
eadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMidd
leware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-07-14 11:07:05 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddlewa
re, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware

2015-07-14 11:07:05 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:

2015-07-14 11:07:05 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened

2015-07-14 11:07:05 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 i
tems (at 0 items/min)
2015-07-14 11:07:05 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023

2015-07-14 11:07:06 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.tripadvisor.co
m/RestaurantSearch?geo=60763&q=New+York+City%2C+New+York&cat=&pid=> (referer: No
ne)

2015-07-14 11:07:06 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

2015-07-14 11:07:06 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 281,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 46932,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 14, 5, 37, 6, 929000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 14, 5, 37, 5, 474000)}
2015-07-14 11:07:06 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to debug your code with `print` statements?

I tried to execute your parser. If I copy the provided code as is I get the same result because the spider class `scrapingtestSpider` has no `parse` method and it does not get called.

If I do some formatting of your code (I indent everything under `start_urls` to be in the class) I get some errors that helper-methods are not defined by their global name.

If I go further and leave only the to `parse` methods for the crawler I get other errors mentioning that `tripadvisor_item` is not defined.... So the code is not really working.

Try to format your code better in your IDE and add `print` messages to your `parse` methods to see if they get called or not. the main `parse` method should be entered when Scrapy crawls the first URL. I think it won't work.

And by the way the callback you add to the `Request` is named bad too:

```
yield Request(url=tripadvisor_item['url'], meta={'tripadvisor_item': tripadvisor_item}, callback=self.parse_search_page)
```

should be changed to

```
yield Request(url=tripadvisor_item['url'], meta={'tripadvisor_item': tripadvisor_item}, callback=self.parse_fetch_review)
```

when you fix the indentation problems.

And at the end of the `parse_fetch_review` method `return` or `yield` the `tripadvisor_item` you created in the parse method.

Comment: Oh wow cant believe I forgot to indent, I work with interactive IDE's so when working with Scrapy its hard for a beginner to notice such small mistakes.